# revtex4-1 Package babel error

Tags: babel, revtex

The file used to run perfectly until few weeks ago. I don't remember editing the file. When I revisited the file today. I'm getting Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet.

I checked multiple solutions from the forum and none of them seem to work. Most of the answered questions were for manually entered bibliography. Whereas I use .bib file generated by Mendeley and the error seems to be from main text to me.

As I said, this file used to compile without any errors. I'm relatively new to latex so I can't figure out what could have went wrong. I'd really appreciate if someone could help.

```latex
\documentclass[aip,graphicx]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\preprint{AIP/123-QED}

...  my text

\end{document}
```

This is how my log file look

[LOG FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ2lx.png)

[image]

Comment: Looks like Mendeley exports a `.bib` file with something like `language = {en},` apparently, your bibliography style tries to pass that on to babel, but `en` is not a valid `babel` language name. Tell Mendeley not to export `language` or to export `language` in a format understandable to `babel` (`language = {english}` would probably work). I can only run tests if you can share the code of a problematic `.bib` entry with us

Comment: Please note that screenshots of `.log` files can pose accessibility issues for people with screen readers or vision problems. Please try to post the relevant bits as code/text in the future. You can copy them from the `.log` file, which you can open with your favourite text editor.

Comment: @moewe You were correct. My .bib file contained language = {en}. I went and manually edited it this time and that fixed my issue. But I still don't know how to tell Mendeley not to export language. I guess I'll keep digging to find answer to that. Anyways, thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Currently `babel` understands BCP 47 tags, but it's a very very recent feature. Without the `bib` file I cannot tell, but it might work if you upgrade `babel`. See  https://github.com/latex3/babel/wiki/What's-new-in-babel-3.43